# get all users who is not inside group

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to get all users from a m:n association who is not a member of a specific group.

After a couple hours of trying and searching for something related this is what I came up with. But it doesn't solve my problem 100%

```
router.get('/:group_id/notmembers', function(req, res) {
  models.User.findAll({
    include: [
      { model: models.Group,
        through: {
          model: models.User_Group,
          where: {
            GroupId: {[Op.notIn] : [req.params.group_id] },
          },
        },
        required: true,
      }
    ],
  }).then(function(groups) {
    res.send(groups);
  });
});
```

The code I've written so far returns all users who are part of another group instead of the specific group_id, this would work in a scenario where a user could only be member of one group. In my scenario users can be a member of multiple groups, therefore this doesn't work for me.

any help appreciated!

**edit:**

No one knows?

Comment: Just so I understand: you're looking to fetch users that are not a part of a given group?

Comment: That is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After blood sweat and tears I finally figured it out.

by setting the required variable to false I can include all db entries for the specific group_id, even if the users don't have it. From there I just select all entries where there is not a Group.id leaving only the users who aren't part of that specific group left.

```
router.get('/:group_id/notmembers', function(req, res) {
  models.User.findAll({
    include: [
      { model: models.Group,
        through: {
          model: models.User_Group,
          where: {
            GroupId: req.params.group_id,
          },
        },
        required: false,
      }
    ],
    where: {
      '$Groups.id$' : null,
    }
  }).then(function(groups) {
    res.send(groups);
  });
});
```